# Determine the set of values of $x$ such that this series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine the set of values of $x$ such that this series converge:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n} x^n$$

**My work:**

If $x\geq e$, we have

$$\frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n} x^n \geq \frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n} e^n = \frac{e^{2n}+e^n}{e^{2n}+n} > 1$$

Therefore the series diverge if $x\geq e$

Now, if $0 \leq x < e$, we have:

$$\frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n} x^n = \frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n} e^n \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n = \frac{e^{2n}+e^n}{e^{2n}+n}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n < \frac{e^{2n}+e^n}{e^{2n}}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n=(1+e^{-n})\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n < 2\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n$$

Therefore

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n} x^n <  \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} 2\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n = 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^n$$

The last series is known to converge for $0 \leq \frac{x}{e} < 1$, or $0 \leq x < e$.

However, I'm having problems when $x$ is negative. I guess we must have $x> -e-1$, but that is nothing more than intuition that I found by estimating a lot.

---

**Questions:**

Is the first (positive $x$) part correct?

How to do the negative $x$ part? Hints and solutions are equally welcome.

Comment: You don't need to do the negative part. Hint: if a power series converges for some $x$, then it converges absolutely for all $x'$ such that $|x'| < |x|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the ratio test? The ratio test tells you that the (power) series $\sum a_n$ converges if 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \Big| < 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big| \frac{\frac{e^{n+1}+1}{e^{2n+2}+n}x^{n+1}}{\frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n}x^n} \Big| < 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big| \frac{(e^{n+1}+1)(e^{2n}+n)}{(e^{2n+2}+n)(e^n+1)}x \Big| < 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big| \frac{e^{n+1}e^{2n}}{e^{2n+2}e^n}x \Big| < 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Big| e^{-1}x \Big| < 1 \iff |x|<e
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with absolute values may be simpler.

You may write, as $n \to +\infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{e^n+1}{e^{2n}+n}\times x^n\right|=e^{-n}\frac{1+e^{-n}}{1+ne^{-2n}}\times |x|^n\sim e^{-n}|x|^n=\left|\frac{x}{e}\right|^n,
$$ then, your power series is convergent **if and only if** $|x|<e$.

Both cases (positive and negative values of $x$) are then considered.